# Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose' in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose, cloud

When we try to deploy our nodejs app in heroku that show us this problem !
by the way I have large app that content a lot of routes. I are not knew if can deploy it with this way I have litter confuse.

```
//package.json
     "scripts": {
                "start": "node ./bin/www",
                "dev": "nodemon ./bin/ww"
            },
```

for runing Heroku : `npm start`

```
  2021-10-17T19:17:50.244905+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244906+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244906+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/users.js
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244906+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/index.js
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244907+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244907+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/bin/www
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244907+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244908+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244908+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244909+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244909+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/users.js:10:16)
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244909+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244910+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244910+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244910+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244911+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244911+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244911+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244911+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/routes/users.js',
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244912+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/routes/index.js',
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244912+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/app.js',
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244912+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/bin/www'
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244913+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.244913+00:00 app[web.1]: }
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.261989+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.262348+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.269748+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! project-work@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.269860+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.269999+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.270110+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the project-work@0.0.0 start script.
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.270230+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.274000+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.274070+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.274112+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-10-17T19_17_50_270Z-debug.log
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.422905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.494116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2021-10-17T19:17:50.498518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2021-10-17T19:17:52.375838+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command  `
```

Comment: All of your dependencies need to be properly defined  in your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`. Install `mongoose` locally using `npm install` or `yarn add`, commit the updated package and lock files, then push again.

Comment: thx alooooot bro that's works